# partition detected as /dev/sdb without identifier

Tags: partitioning, disk

Today I am changing my disk configuration, moving my documents on several disks.
But I'm confronted with a problem I have never seen before, the unique partition on my new disk is recognized as /dev/sdb instead of /dev/sdb1:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

$ df
Filesystem               1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                        4041556         0    4041556   0% /dev
tmpfs                        813524      9744     803780   2% /run
/dev/sda5                  57349152  42748896   11664000  79% /
tmpfs                       4067620     20260    4047360   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          5120         4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                       4067620         0    4067620   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                     97280     65520      31760  68% /boot/efi
tmpfs                        813524       156     813368   1% /run/user/1000
/home/augustin/.Private    57349152  42748896   11664000  79% /home/augustin
/dev/sdb                 1922729864 860147888  964889864  48% /media/augustin/HOME
```

I have never seen a partition recognized as /dev/sdb.
So is that normal? Maybe I made a mistake such as `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb`? I don't have history of my commands so I can't investigate this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please prefix your commands with `LC_ALL=C` for English text, and update your question with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not normal, but it's not unusual either. It's entirely possible to format the disk itself (like you suggested, `mkfs .... /dev/sdb`) instead of creating a partition table and partitions and then formatting a partition. See discussion on [the merits of a partitionless filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14010/70524) over on Unix & Linux.

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't know it was possible. Do you think it is possible to create a partition in this disk and get all data already saved in it? Otherwise I will keep this configuration ;)

Comment: Not without destroying the filesystem that's already there. If you can copy the data already in it elsewhere, then you can create a partition table and partitions as you normally would.

Comment: @augustinvm It's not a problem, anyway to use unpartitioned media. Ask yourself: "do i need to partition this one?". If it's an extra disk used for data storage, than it'd be pretty OK to leave it as is.