# fsck repair disk but needs to be ran at each startup

Tags: disk

I've now been trying to fix it for some days now without success and I don't find same issue on the web.
For your information, this thread is linked with a previous one: [partition detected as /dev/sdb without identifier](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980630/partition-detected-as-dev-sdb-without-identifier)

So there is the issue:
I have a hard disk without any partition (due to an error from my part, I made a fs on a whole disk instead of a partition. While it works and it wasn't a problem, I stayed with this configuration)

Recently I tried to read this disk from Windows with unofficial utilities, and it corrupted my fs creating a windows partition at the beginning of the disk.

What I done was to remove this part (without formatting) and then run

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -yf /dev/sdb
```

This command seems to repair my disk and then I'm able to mount and use it.
But at next startup, I need to run it again for my disk to be mountable.

I found an issue with gdisk:

```
 sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
 GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

 Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!
 Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table
 instead of main partition table!

 Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

 Partition table scan:
   MBR: protective
   BSD: not present
   APM: not present
   GPT: damaged

 ****************************************************************************
 Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
 verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
 ****************************************************************************

 Command (? for help): v

 Problem: The CRC for the main partition table is invalid. This table may be
 corrupt. Consider loading the backup partition table ('c' on the recovery &
 transformation menu). This report may be a false alarm if you've already
 corrected other problems.

 Identified 1 problems!
```

I cannot find how to repair it so I come here now.
I would like the disk to be auto-mounted at startup but it is currently not possible.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: The disc is likely failing and you should back up your data as a first step. You can run smartmontools to check the disc health but I advise you replace it.

Comment: smartmontools doesn't seem to find any disk failure... What's surprising is that this issue has appeared after windows attempt to read it... I didn't think it can corrupt Linux filesystems...

Comment: If you are reading linux file systems (ext4) from windows that will do it.